# How to know the datatype of the remaining data on a Parcelable?

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent, xsd, parcelable

I am implementing a sort of mapping between a XSD object into a Parcelable on Android. Everything goes fine except when I have a more complex xsd element which contains a elements which are optional (minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1').

I need to write my bean constructor with the format:

```
private Bean (Parcel in) {
    super();
    this.setId(in.readInd());
    this.setComplexData((ComplexClass) in.readParcelable(ComplexClass.class
            .getClassLoader()));
    this.setComplexData2((ComplexClass2) in.readParcelable(ComplexClass2.class
            .getClassLoader()));

}
```

but both the complex data is optional.

When I had just one optional data, I was using:

```
    if(in.dataAvail() >0)
                this.setComplexData((ComplexClass) in.readParcelable(ComplexClass.class
            .getClassLoader()));
```

But if both are optional, I cant do that. Therefore, I was wondering if there is some way to identify what is the object within the parcelable, some sort of way to check the class signature? In that sense, I could check if the data is ComplexClass1 or 2 and do the read.